# Compiler/language runtime vs. Middleware

Tags: c, compiler-construction, operating-system, runtime, middleware

What are the specific operations a language runtime does that an operating system does not? How is a language runtime different from a middleware?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the operating system and the runtime. [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libc) is a good example of a language runtime and the linked article on Wikipedia gives a good overview of what it does. Generally the goal of a language runtime is to provide implementations of standard basic functionality which is likely to be implemented differently between the operating systems the language supports, or functionality which is extremely common, but not provided by the operating system.

Middleware is a very general concept but it simply refers to software placed between two systems as an abstraction layer. You could consider a language runtime as a form of middleware in some contexts.